# How to disable KDE Marble map movement?

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma, marble

I am using KDE Marble API on C++ Qt5.5.

When I drag and move left mouse, map continues moving after the mouse release.

How can I disable this feature on a Marble Widget?

I tried to see inputhandler or set.. functions, but couldn't see any related function to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`marbleWidget->inputHandler()->setInertialEarthRotationEnabled( false );` is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I find that it is simpler to

```
this->setInputEnabled(false);
```

and control everything about the map with my own buttons